# Python get the code from a link or server

Tags: python-3.x

Okey so i dont want to put my code in my python.py file
i want to load it from a pastebin/raw link.

example:

```
import requests
import re

r = requests.get('https://pastebin.com/raw/example')

run(r)
```

can this be posible in any way ?

why i need to do this ?
i have more than 25 scripts i need to update on 5 different systems, so i dont want to go in each system and update each py file
so i just need to edit my Pastebins from 1 system.

thanks.

Comment: Maybe you could just try to use rsync to distribute your scripts on each system.

Comment: there are many sensible way to deploy production code. this does not seem to be one of them...

Comment: Your DONT want to "load your code from a pastebin raw link" - well, unless you want to give script kiddies the keys of your systems of course...